# Conditionally select compiler based on its version

Tags: c++, cmake

## Goals

Make `cmake` select `clang++` if its version is above `10`; otherwise, use `g++`. If `clang++` is below `10` and the default `g++` is below `10.1`, use `g++-10` (`REQUIRED`).

This is to achieve compiler fallback.

## Background

As kindly noted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944545/9379639), one should set the default compiler before the `project` keyword.

Instead of using

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++
```

or

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
```

I used the following statements with reference to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29904501/9379639):

```
find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
    NAMES $ENV{CXX} clang++ PATHS ENV PATH NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 10)
  find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
      NAMES $ENV{CXX} g++ PATHS ENV PATH NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
  if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 10.1)
    find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
      NAMES $ENV{g++-10} g++-10 PATHS ENV PATH NO_DEFAULT_PATH REQUIRED)
  endif()
endif()
```

## Problem

The compiler is not set to `g++` when the version of `clang++` is less than `10`, but I could check that `cmake` passes the branch

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 10)
```

I do not understand this behavior. And are there any alternative to this without using command line arguments?

### UPDATE

This question was asked in acknowledgment of the fact that setting a compiler in `CMakeLists.txt` is discouraged.

@KamilCuk suggested two ways to achieve what I stated, and one may take those suggestions if they want to.

Here's what I did.

#### TL;DR

Do not specify a compiler in `CMakeLists.txt`.

#### My suggestion

This is contrary to what I have previously done in this question.

I scrapped all the configuration logic from `CMakeLists.txt` and decided to create a shell file that extracts compiler versions and select an appropriate compiler. This way of configuration is quite well-known, which can be found in many popular repositories such as [ImageMagick](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick) and [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow).

Comment: Imagine there is no `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION`. How would you get it? You have to write the code yourself, `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION` is set __after__ the compiler _has been_ chosed.

Comment: @KamilCuk I just found that `CMAKE_CXX_COMILER_VERSION` before `project` prints out nothing. You are absolutely right. Do I have to provide command line arguments to specify a compiler?

Comment: You have to write _the logic_ that you want to write, somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write the logic in cmake, you could write something along:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

# Before project()!!!
execute_process(COMMAND clang++ --version OUTPUT_VARIABLE result)
string(REGEX REPLACE "[^0-9]* ([0-9]+).*" "\\1" clang_version "${result}") # extract the version with some regex
execute_process(COMMAND g++ --version OUTPUT_VARIABLE result)
string(REGEX REPLACE "[^0-9]* ([0-9]+).*" "\\1" gcc_version "${result}") # extract the version with some regex
# write your super condition here and set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER depending on it
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
if (gcc_version LESS 10)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
endif()


project(blabla) # uses CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER and configures cmake
```

You could also use `include(CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler)` to determine the version, or use the template files from cmake from `CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp.in` from cmake installation path that is used by `CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler` internally.

Comment: Can I verify that `CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler` is something to do with `configure_file`?

Comment: Why not just [browse it's source](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake). It's one of many modules shipped and used by cmake. `configure_file` I think is called inside `CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID` inside `CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake`